# Why combined lambda expressions don't work in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Delegates can be combined, so:

```
MethodInvoker del = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Delegate 1"); };
del += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Delegate 2"); };
del.Invoke();
```

Outputs:

```
Delegate 1 
Delegate 2
```

Since it calls both methods, I tried this to see if it would work:

```
Func<Person, bool> filters = person => person.Name.Contains("John");
filters += person => person.Age >= 18;

List<Person> persons = getPersons();

persons.Where(filters);
```

But it doesn't, only last is applied (in this case,  `person => person.Age >= 18`).

My question is: Why not? Is it possible to implement this? (not that I would rewrite Linq's extension methods just to implement this, but would be cool if possible)

**Note:**
I know that in LINQ to Objects, doing this would be similar, as execution is deferred:

```
persons.Where( x => x.Name.Contains( nameFilter )).Where( x => x.Age >= 18 );
```

But that's not what I'm interested in.

Comment: Does combining two `Func<T, bool>` delegates cause them to AND one another? I highly doubt it. Remember that you're actually returning values from these two delegates. I presume everything before the last return value in the invocation list gets discarded.

Comment: I don't see how it could work: one function says the result is false, the other says the result is true. When actions are combined, they are both executed, but the question of which result to use doesn't come up, because there is no result.

Comment: you can write And and Or methods that combine bool-returning delegates the way you want: `Func<Person, bool> And(Func<Person, bool> a, Func<Person, bool> b) { return (Person p) => a(p) && b(p); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that both filters are executed, but only the return value of the last delegate is used. That is how delegates work according to the specification. Like the comments say, I can't imagine how this would work differently. You're alluding that the results should be `AND`ed, but why can't they be `OR`ed? What would happen if the results were `strings`?

Answer (score 1):

This works only with Action delegates, not with Func delegates, since a delegate call can only return one single result.

Comment: Great! Would this work with Linq to entities / Nhibernate too? Or depends on the implementation?

Comment: @Andre I'm guessing those frameworks are parsing lambda expression trees. If that's the case you could get some weird runtime, not compile time, errors from combining Lambda expressions.

Comment: Linq as interface to o/r-mappers works in a completely different way. The lambda expression is not executed at all. Instead, its syntactical structure is analyzed and converted into a SQL statement. Therefore multicasting will not work.